# How can I recreate these gradients? in illustrator or Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo, gradient

[image]

Hi all! I've been trying to recreate the gradients inside the two coloured shapes in this logo. I've tried using gradients, hand drawing them with brushes, inner glow and a whole bunch of other stuff. I must be doing something wrong.

Any advice out there?

Thanks

Comment: Post your best attempt. It'll be easier for us to help you go forward if we're not starting at square one.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least 4 options in Illustrator to use/combine:

1. Mesh Tool
2. Gradient Tool
3. Drop shadow effect
4. Blend Tool

Here is 5 minutes example of Mesh+Drop Shadow tool:

[image]

Comment: 5. Gradient Mesh.

Comment: @Scott I wrote Blend twice (formatting error). I used mesh actually in the example :)

Comment: I saw that afterwards :) I just read the list and realized it wasn't there :)